# Formatting Go time with Z precision

Tags: go

I have the following Go code:

```
now := time.Now().UTC().String()
log.Info("time is: " + now)
```

When this runs it prints out:

```
time is: 2020-08-21 10:34:43.3547088 +0000 UTC
```

I only want time precision in HH:mm:ss such that it would print out as:

```
time is: 2020-08-21 10:34:43Z
```

What do I need to change to format my time correctly? Must contain that "Z" at the end.

Comment: if you can live with the date-time separator "T" from RFC3339: `time.Now().UTC().Format(time.RFC3339)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [time format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) to get time as what you want.

```
func main() {
    now := time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05Z")
    fmt.Println("time is: " + now)
}
```

in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xx3on06wbmO)

Answer (score 1):

The format you are trying to print is not from one of the standard formats defined in the time package. Its so close to `RFC3339` barring the `T` notation. But still [Format()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) function allows you to provide a custom format string to show how your time should be printed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now().UTC()
    fmt.Printf("time is: %v", now.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05Z"))
    //fmt.Println("time is: " + now)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
now := time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05Z")
log.Info("time is: " + now)
```

ref: https://dev.to/mahbubzulkarnain/golang-time-format-22j0

Comment: run [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/usOTuuGnVdW)